# ImportError: cannot import name objects

Tags: python, facebook-ads-api

I am using python Facebook Ads SDK, I try to get my ad accounts:

```
from facebookads import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads import objects
my_app_id = 'my_app_id'
my_app_secret = 'my_app_secret'
my_access_token = 'my_access_token'
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

me = objects.AdUser(fbid='me')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())
print my_accounts
```

but when I run the script I got ImportError: `cannot import name objects`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Objects module is removed from python 2.7]  [Link for particular python page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facebookads/)

Answer (score 1):

Since Facebook deprecated v2.8 a few days ago, some might be affected by this.  Try this revised code.

```
from facebookads import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.user import User

my_app_id = 'my_app_id'
my_app_secret = 'my_app_secret'
my_access_token = 'my_access_token'

FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

me = User(fbid='me')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())

print my_accounts
```

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 2.9.1 version of the facebook marketing API? if yes - there is no object to import in this version. is was there till v2.8.1

Answer (score 0):

All the facebook ads objects that you need to import are under AdObjects starting v2.7 for PHP and Python ads sdks.